# Invert "matrix of polynomials" for a change of presentation of an Ideal

Tags: polynomials, ideals, groebner-basis

If I start with a polynomial ideal generated by a set of polynomials $f_i$, which is not a standard basis for the ideal, and then I obtain a standard basis for the ideal to be a set of polynomials $g_j$, how can I figure out how to write each $g_j$ as a linear combination of $f_i$?

Because $g_j$ is a standard basis, without much difficulty we can write each $f_i$ as a linear combination of $f_i = \sum_j M_{ij} g_j$, where each $M_{ij}$ is a polynomial. So we have a "matrix of polynomials" describing the "change of presentation" from $g_j$ to $f_i$ (not sure the correct phrasing, as $f_i$ is not a basis, so this is not a change of "basis"... maybe change of generators?).

With this matrix $M_{ij}$ in hand, is there some way I can "invert" it to get the matrix $N_{ij}$, such that $g_j = \sum_i N_{ji} f_i$?

If I knew the proper phrases to describe this process, I could probably search better. So that would be helpful as well.

This question is very related:
[Use / take advantage of Gröbner basis $ G = (g_j)$ to write $f \in I = \langle f_i \rangle$ as a $k$-linear combination of the polynomials in $I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604288/use-take-advantage-of-gr%c3%b6bner-basis-g-g-j-to-write-f-in-i-langle-f)
It shows how one could, in principle, calculate this by carrying extra information along while calculating the standard basis. But I am not calculating the standard basis by hand. The example I am working with is large, and while computer packages can calculate the basis fairly easily (in about 10 minutes with a few GB of memory), they fail if I try to calculate the matrix simultaneously: it quickly runs through all the memory on my computer trying to carry around extra information in case it is needed for the matrix. That is why I want to know if there is some way to use just the basis itself after it is calculated (and the $M_{ij}$ which is not hard to generate from it).

Answer (score 1):

Writing $g$ as a linear combination (with polynomial coefficients) of $f_1,
\ldots,f_r$ is sometimes called "lifting", e.g. [lift](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-2-0/sing_288.htm#SEC328) in Singular and [lift](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_libsingular.html#sage.rings.polynomial.multi_polynomial_libsingular.MPolynomial_libsingular.lift) in SageMath (which uses Singular). The resulting coefficients can be called witnesses to (or a certificate of) the membership of $g$ in the ideal generated by the $f_i$.

I'm not sure exactly how the computation goes, but I think it amounts to finding syzygies of $f_1,\ldots,f_r,g$ where the coefficient of $g$ is a unit (or more generally syzygies of $f_1,\ldots,f_r,g_1,\ldots,g_s$ where the coefficients of $g_j$ are units).
The internal implementation in Singular is found in [idLift](https://github.com/Singular/Singular/blob/39bce01458231034d994a18e2d7a71cc31a48159/kernel/ideals.cc#L1078), which someone might be able to decipher.